# slideToggle: + sign is not updated to -

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to solve the following problems?

1) `+` sign is not properly updated to '-' and vice versa;

2) `My Settings` test disappear after clicking `+` sign for the first time.

```
$(function(){
    $('.myToggler').click(function(e){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        var sign=$(this).children(':first');
        sign.text(sign.text() == '+'?'+':'-');
        e.preventDefault;
    });
});

<div class="myToggler">
    <h3><span class="togglerSign">+</span>
    My Settings</h3>
</div>
<div class="mySlider">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ukomuz/1/edit)*

- You should look for elements using: `.find()`
- and use: `sign.text() == '+'?'-':'+'`

To refresh the knowledge about ***ternary operators*** :

```
[statement]  ?  [if is true]   :  [if is false] ;
sign is '+'  ?  YES?set to'-'  :  NO?set to'+'  ;
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.myToggler').click(function(e){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        var sign=$(this).find('span');
        sign.text(sign.text() == '+'?'-':'+');
        e.preventDefault;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sign=$(this).children(':first');
```

should be

```
var sign=$(this).children('span:first');
```

and

```
sign.text(sign.text() == '+'?'+':'-');
```

should be

```
sign.text(sign.text() == '+'?'-':'+');
```

Comment: or you could use full css traversal i.e. var sign=$(this).children('h3>span.togglersign');

Comment: I tried your solution. Now + My settings is always displayed, but + sign is not changed to -

Comment: see newly edited solution (thanks @SimpleCoder) - you have put the plus and minus the wrong way round in your ternary expression

Answer (score 0):

There are many solution to do it. You can also try this :

```
$(function(){
    $('.myToggler').click(function(e){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        sign = $('.'+this.className+' span:first-child');
        sign.text((sign.text() == "+") ? "-" : "+");
        e.preventDefault;
    });
});​

<div class="myToggler">
    <h3><span class="togglerSign">+</span>My Settings</h3>
</div>
<div class="mySlider"></div>
```